# Windows - "netstat -an -p tcp" NOT Displaying IPv6 Foreign Addresses ("netstat -an" does)

Tags: windows, tcp, ip, ipv6, netstat

On Windows Does anyone know why "netstat -an -p tcp" doesn't display IPv6 addresses, but why "netstat -an" does display them?

I highly doubt it's resolving IPv6 addresses to IPv4s, but this is puzzlibg the hell out of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `netstat /?` in console (or [[MS.Docs]: Netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490947(v=technet.10))):

> `-p proto    Shows connections for the protocol specified by proto; proto
>              may be any of: TCP, UDP, TCPv6, or UDPv6.  If used with the -s
>              option to display per-protocol statistics, proto may be any of:
>              IP, IPv6, ICMP, ICMPv6, TCP, TCPv6, UDP, or UDPv6.`

So, when specifying `-p tcp`, it only displays the *TCP**v4*** connections (by filtering out all the rest), while not specifying any protocol, it displays them all (doesn't filter anything).

Comment: Thank You CristiFati.
More than just learning about my problems, I've started to default to trying to search for previous help topics created as opposed to developer websites. This is kind of embarrassing, but it was a very nice reminder about where to look (although Microsoft's explanation was not as understandable as yours). Thank you very much, again.